# What is the best way to wait for 'WebComponentsReady' event in TestCafe?

Tags: testing, web-component, testcafe, testcase, browser-testing

I want to wait for web components in the page to upgrade before running any TestCafe tests (In other words, wait for `WebComponentsReady` event before running tests). What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

TestCafe starts to execute any action on the page after the `DOMContentReady` event is raised. As I see, the `WebComponentsReady` event can be raised before `DOMContentReady`.
TestCafe allows you to wait for some events in the browser by using ClientFunction:

```
const waitForWebComponentsReady = ClientFunction(() => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        window.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', resolve);
    });
});

await waitForWebComponentsReady();
```

However, note that TestCafe can't guarantee that this code will be executed before the `WebComponentReady` event is raised. As a result, this Promise will not be resolved.

As a solution, you can find another way to identify if the required Web Component is loaded. For example, you can check that some element is visible on the page:

```
await t.expect(Selector('some-element').visible).ok();
```

Meanwhile, TestCafe has a feature suggestion to [add the capability to execute a custom script before page initialization scripts](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/1739). You will be able to use code like this when the feature is implemented:

```
import { ClientFunction } from 'testcafe';

const initScript = `window.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', () => window.WebComponentsLoaded = true);`;

fixture `My Fixture`
    .page `http://example.com`
    .addScriptToEachPage(initScript)
    .beforeEach(async t => {
        await t.expect(ClientFunction(() => window.WebComponentsLoaded)()).ok();
    });
```